How to change Adobe Reader's working directory or move Android directories to SD card?
Maybe incorrect forum but gotta start somewhere...
I just got an old Samsung Galaxy Tab A running Android 7.1.1 for a PDF reader. As the internal storage is very limited, all the files are on an SD card. Whenever I open a PDF, Adobe Reader saves a copy to the internal Download -directory. All annotations are saved on the new copy. If I open the file again from the card, Reader saves another copy in Download. Reader doesn't seem to have option to change its default working dir.
How can I either get Reader to play ball or move the tablet's Downloads, Files etc to the SD card? Tablet's currently unrooted.
